# After action_send Intent backbutton needs to be pressed twice to close activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I use the following code to share some text to other apps:

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "my subject");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "my text body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Empfehlen über"));
```

this is my onBackpressed() method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    setActionbarTitle("Einstellungen");
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0); // prevent activity to slide down on finish
}
```

When starting the `action_send` chooser and then clicking the backbutton the choosing screen is closed as it should. But to get back to my previous activity I then need to click twice on the backbutton.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: And back working on single click if your remove the 2 lines from onBackPressed()?

Comment: @Astha also not working